# Not able to login lost mobile and recovery code

Tags: github, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Please help me to login in GitHub account.

I changed my old mobile so Google auth not installed and lost the saved recovery keys.

I can access my account from the terminal. I know username and password.

I can't log in to GitHub. I have a registered mobile number.

Please help me in this regards.

I sent many emails to GitHub but didn't get any response yet.

Comment: There is now (Oct. 2022) an [Improved account recovery flow in case of a lost 2FA device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309).

Answer (score -1):

Oct. 2022: see also "[How to recover GitHub password without using 2FA credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309)".

---

Jun. 2019: Then you should use ["Authenticating with a fallback number"](https://help.github.com/en/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials#authenticating-with-a-fallback-number)

> If you lose access to your primary TOTP app or phone number, you can provide a two-factor authentication code sent to your fallback number to automatically regain access to your account.

It should be set [as shown here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-two-factor-authentication-recovery-methods)

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/2fa/add-fallback-sms-number-button.png]

Comment: I can't log in and I don't find any message or email of recovery code in my account. I didn't set fallback number I think.

Comment: @niravdhanorkar in that case, only GItHub support can sort this out: do check next time that you have your fallback recoveries in place for your GitHub account.